# svelte dialog slide down animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svelte

I have this svelte component and I want to do a slide down animation when it get's closed. The slide up animation is working, however the slide down not. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that?

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    export let show = false;
    export let title: string | undefined;

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    let dialog: HTMLDialogElement | undefined;

    $: if (dialog != null && show && !dialog.open) {
        dialog.showModal();
        dispatch('open');
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
        show = false;
        dialog?.close();
        dispatch('close');
    };
</script>

<dialog
    bind:this={dialog}
    aria-live="assertive"
    on:close={closeModal}
    on:click|self={() => dialog?.close()}
>
    <div on:click|stopPropagation>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-title-container">
                {#if title}
                    <h2 class="modal-title">{title}</h2>
                {/if}
            </div>

            <button on:click={closeModal}> X </button>
        </div>
        <section class="modal-content">
            <slot />
        </section>
    </div>
</dialog>

<style lang="scss">
    dialog {
        animation: slide-down 0.7s ease-out;
    }

    dialog[open] {
        animation: slide-up 0.7s ease-out;
    }

    dialog[open]::backdrop {
        animation: backdrop-fade-in 0.7s ease-out forwards;
    }

    @keyframes slide-up {
        from {
            transform: translateY(100%);
        }
        to {
            transform: translateY(0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes slide-down {
        to {
            transform: translateY(-110%);
        }
    }
    @keyframes backdrop-fade-in {
        0% {
            background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0%);
        }

        100% {
            background-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 25%);
        }
    }
</style>
```

I saw this article and the fade transition is working, however not the slide down https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it on my own.
I updated my keyframes like that:

```
@keyframes slide-down {
    from {
        display: block;
    }

    to {
        transform: translate(0%, 100%);
        display: none;
    }
}
```